# NSKeyedUnarchiver error after renaming Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsdata, nskeyedunarchiver

I just renamed my Xcode project and when I ran it I got this error:

> 2015-11-14 05:32:42.337 Buck Tracker[3537:1456100] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (iBudgeter.Record) for key (NS.objects); the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked'

The `Buck Tracker` is the new name and `iBudgeter` is the original name. `Record` is a custom `NSObject` I created to store some data.

I tried renaming the project back to `iBudgeter` but it didn't work. Reverting to a previous version in git did help but I got the same error when I renamed it again.

So any suggestions?

Comment: Does `Buck Tracker` conform to the `NSCoding` protocol?

Comment: have you tried to do a 'clean' ?

Comment: @hal9000 I did but it didn't work

Comment: @JAL What should I do to conform it to `NSCoding`?

Comment: Do you have existing users with stored data that you want to preserve access to?

Comment: @robmayoff yeah in fact reseting the simulator works but this app is already on App Store so I can't do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't change your project name. Just change the display name. It's the "Bundle display name" entry in your Info.plist. You'll probably need to add the entry.

[image: adding Bundle display name to Info.plist]

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34280595/77567) if you want to change the display name of an OS X app.

Comment: Wow you are life saver! Didn't know I can do that :D

Comment: How do you do this if you want to change the name not just on the display name?

Answer (score 19):

another way is to fix the name of the class used for NSCoding. You simply have to use:

- `NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("Record", forClass: Record.self` before serializing
- `NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(Record.self, forClassName: "Record")` before deserializing

wherever needed.

Looks like iOS extensions prefix the class name with the extension's name.

Comment: I spent half a day on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

In Case if you moved your file to another module, you would need to add additional information

```
NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("OldModule.ClassName", for: ClassName.self)
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(ClassName.self, forClassName: "OldModule.ClassName")
```

Comment: This is the correct answer when modules changed or target was copied etc. Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the old app and run it again works for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue last night.  Sorted it after 3 hours investigating by simply changing the 'Product Name' (under Build Settings) back to the original value.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error after only renaming a ClassA that uses the NSCoding protocol to ClassB.

For me the problem was that I had used the ClassA in my UserDefaults.
So there was the old name ClassA stored in the UserDefaults .plist.

When the Application was starting it tried to read the .plist and because there was a mismatch in the names the Application crashes.

Solution for me was just to **delete the user defaults and run the app again** and it worked.

To delete the defaults I used this command in terminal:

`defaults delete buldle-identifier`