# NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile crashes when loading classes created from a different target

Tags: ios, xcode, serialization, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I have a PLIST file that has been created using production version of the application and added as a resource to the project. The name of the target of production version is "little pony". In order to help with application testing there is another version built though a different target under the same project "little pony beta".
At runtime, beta application tries to load PLIST and crashes with message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (little pony.Layer) for key (NS.objects); the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked'
```

It seems, that the PLIST should contain `little pony beta.Layer` instead of `little pony.Layer` class in order for the loading to succeed.

Is there any way to make `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile` use different namespace for this to work? Of course, I don't want to create two different sets of pre-compiled data, as this is CPU intensive task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37162921/279813

The solution proposes to change the name of the class for NSCoding by using

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver setClass:[Layer self] forClassName:@"little pony beta.Layer"];
```